# Why Array#=== is not defined while Range#=== is?

Tags: ruby

The case equality operator Range#=== exists and uses Range#include? internally if I am not mistaken.

```ruby
# prints "foo"
case 2
when (1..3)
  puts "foo"
end
```

I was wondering why this is not the case for the Array class ... It breaks the principle of least surprise in my opinion. I'd expect this to work, but it does not.

```ruby
# does not print "foo"
case 2
when [1, 2, 3]
  puts "foo"
end
```

Is it for performance reasons ?

Comment: Would `[2,3,2] === [3,2,2]` as they have the same elements, just differente order?

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong. `Array#===` **is** defined (To be more precise, `Array#===` is not defined per se, but it inherits). If it were not defined, then your code would raise an error.

When `a` is an `Array`, `a === obj` is defined to be `true` when `a == obj`, and your code does not print `"foo"` because `[1, 2, 3]` is not `2`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know *why* there's no `Array#===` that behaves like `Range#===`, i.e. retuning `true` when the argument is a member of the array.

Comment: @sawa: you are right, [1, 2, 3] === 2 does not raise because the "===" method used by Array instances is inherited (from Kernel#=== mixed in the Object class), my original post might not have been clear enough on that point. Stefan is also right though, what I really want to know is why there is no Array#=== that overrides the inherited Kernel#===. [1, 2, 3] === 2 returning true makes as much sense to me as (1..3) === 2 returning true.

Answer (score 1):

It's like that because `===` is used internally by case statements.

`case (4..10)` matching when given `5` makes sense; `case [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` less so. (If you need to match any element of an array in a case statement, you can splat it: `case *[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that Array somewhat breaks character, by not providing the "if a were a set, then a === b is whether b is part of a" semantics that other core classes provide. That said, the main purpose of the === in Ruby is to allow classes to support case...when statement.

I guess that the difference comes from how case...when statements involving arrays would be handled:

```
case [1, 2]
when [1, 2]
when [1, 2, 3]
when [1, 2, [1, 2]]
end
```

You can see that it is possible to argument that all scenarios would match, each one for a different reason.

I think in the end was just too ambiguous. As mentioned earlier, the splat operator can be used to cover discrete set use cases.

Since ranges are not nested structures, these type of questions simply don't apply.